# Creating Constraint layout uisng java file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create constraint layout using Mainactivity.java but I am facing some problems. I'm getting the below output.

[image]

The constraint layout isn't matching the size of parent.

I have created 2 classes 1 is `MainActivity.java` and another is `MyConstraintLayout.Java`

MyconstraintLayout.java

```
package com.example.checkbox;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

public class MyConstraintLayout extends ConstraintLayout {
    public MyConstraintLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        setId(generateViewId());
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layout = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        setLayoutParams(layout);
        setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.teal_200));

        createWidgets(context);
    }


    void createWidgets(Context context){
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams l1 = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button b1 = new Button(context);
        b1.setText("Button");
        b1.setId(generateViewId());
        addView(b1);
        setLayoutParams(l1);

        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams l2 = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button b2 = new Button(context);
        b2.setText("Button");
        b2.setId(generateViewId());
        addView(b2);
        setLayoutParams(l2);


        l1.bottomToBottom = getId();
        l1.topToTop = getId();
        l1.endToEnd= getId();
        l1.startToStart = getId();


        l2.bottomToBottom = getId();
        l2.topToBottom = b1.getId();
        l2.endToEnd= getId();
        l2.startToStart = getId();


    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.checkbox;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyConstraintLayout parent_layout = new MyConstraintLayout(this);
        setContentView(parent_layout);
    }
}
```

Don't have any XML file.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setLayoutParams()` on the `ConstraintLayout` and not on the child `View`s that you've added to the `ConstraintLayout`. You should be doing something like this instead:

```
b1.setLayoutParams(l1);
b2.setLayoutParams(l2);
```